# Shell Script logical operator for conditions

Tags: shell

```
 $i="500,600"
 $j="600"

 if[$i -ne $j]; then
    #some line
 else
    #some line
 fi
```

This if condition is not going inside.

this if condition fails. else is pass.

how is this possible

can someone help me on this

Comment: Spacing is important, use: `if [ $i != $j ]; then`

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to consider the "[" sign as a command (in fact it is one indeed), whose last argument must be a "]". So you must ensure that there is a space after [ and all of its arguments go to the proper place. In your case:

```
if [ "$i" -ne "$j" ]
 then
     # some code
 else
     # some code
fi
```

Since [ is a command, you might want to omit the if structure and use logical operators, taking advantage of lazy evaluation. The following means the same:

```
[ "$i" -ne "$j" ] && {
    echo "hello" ;
    echo "world" ;
} || { 
    echo "bye bye" ;
    echo "world" ;
}
```

Comment: yes.. but i have to use != instead of -ne if we compare a string and integer . i tried with [ "$i" != "$j" ] then it worked perfectly.. Is that mean if we compare a string and integer then do we need to use != instead of -ne?

Comment: Yes, it goes like this. Exactly speaking, != is for arbitrary string comparison, while -ne is useful if both of its arguments can be interpreted as an integer.